# How to read a PowerPoint document and store its slides into Slide objects?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

How to read a PowerPoint document and store its slides into Slide objects using C#?

So if I run this code and load the ppt file:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();  
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;  
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(@"D:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\presenting.ppt");
```

then how to get for example, just the first slide and save it into object/variable `Slide first_slide`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use VBA, not C#, so can't give you directly usable code examples, but here's approximately how you can do this in VBA:

```
Sub Example()

Dim oPres As Presentation
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim sFileName As String
Dim aSlides() As Slide

sFileName = "c:\somefolder\mypres.pptx"

' Open the presentation
Set oPres = Presentations.Open(sFileName)

' Prepare an array to hold slide objects
ReDim aSlides(1 To oPres.Slides.Count)

' Add each slide in the presentation to the array
For Each oSl In oPres.Slides
    Set aSlides(oSl.SlideIndex) = oSl
Next

' Now you have an array of slides
' Do what you will with it

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Presentation object has a Slides collection that you can index into.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please provide some more detail, maybe some code example. I'm not that good in this.